# Ansible error stating: 'apt_repository' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to just run a playbook with:
`ansible-playbook roles/java/tasks/debian.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts`

and the output is as follows:

```
ERROR! 'apt_repository' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/Users/awest1/Workspace/ansible-playbooks/roles/java/tasks/debian.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Setup oracle java deb repo
  ^ here
```

---

The yml file that I am trying to play has this head:

```
- name: Setup oracle java deb repo
   apt_repository:
     repo: "ppa:webupd8team/java"
     update_cache: yes
```

I would appreciate any direction given. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to run tasks list as a playbook.

To make it work, write a simple playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include: roles/java/tasks/debian.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input

```
- name: Setup oracle java deb repo
   apt_repository:
     repo: "ppa:webupd8team/java"
     update_cache: yes
```

is **invalid** YAML.

This is correct (value for `name` is a scalar spread over multiple lines):

```
- name: Setup oracle java deb repo
   apt_repository
     repo "ppa:webupd8team/java"
     update_cache yes
```

And this is correct as well (proper indentation at 2 indents):

```
- name: Setup oracle java deb repo
  apt_repository:
    repo: "ppa:webupd8team/java"
    update_cache: yes
```

You probably want the later.

Comment: Doesn't really explain *why* it is invalid YAML.  Something to do with lines and indentations, but not really making it clear what.